# Computed signal dependencies

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-signals

Question to the Angular experts about Signals:

When you create a `computed()` signal, dependencies are automatically tracked, but according to the docs only for signals that were previously read.

If I understand this correctly, would the following be problematic since the `every` could potentially shortcircuit if the one of the first items is not selected, making the computed function only track a subset of the items?

```
const allSelected = computed(() => {     
    return selectableItems.every(item => item.selected()); 
});
```

To be clear: `item.selected()` is a signal as well.

It seems to be running fine, but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 4):

Your particular issue of concern shouldn't be an issue.  For `selectableItems` to be *true* all items will have to be evaluated.  If an item turns to *false*, it doesn't matter if an item with a greater index becomes false in the future because logically the result of `every` will still be the same.

That being said, you will have issues if `selectableItems` can have items added or removed.

An extreme example is if `selectableItems` is empty when `computed` is called.  At that point, no signals will fire and the value will never be checked again.

A less extreme issue would be if an item is added at a later point.  The value of `allSelected` won't be evaluated until one of the previous items have their value changed.  If all the old items are *true* and the new item is *false*, then `allSelected` will be wrong.

If `selectableItems` can change, then a better design might be to make `selectableItems` a signal instead of all the individual items, and then use update when an item is changed.

```
// changed selectableItems to items to make example shorter.
items = signal([] as SelectableItem[]);

const allSelected = computed(() => this.items().every(item => item.selected));
addItem(item: SelectableItem) {
  this.items.update(x => [...x, item]);
}
updateItem(item: SelectableItem) {
  this.items.update(x => {
    const index = x.indexOf(item);
    return [...x.slice(0, index), item, ...x.slice(index + 1, 0)];
  });
}
```

**Advanced Solution**

If you wanted to keep the logic of your array outside of your component you could even [create your own signal](https://blog.stackademic.com/crafting-custom-angular-signals-7ef83b2e751f).  The solution below adds methods to a writable signal and uses undocumented but exported functions from [core signal primitives](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/17.0.x/packages/core/primitives/signals/src/signal.ts).

```
export interface ArraySignal<T> extends WritableSignal<T[]> {
  updateElement(item: T, updateFn: (x: T) => T): void;
  push(item: T): void;
}

export function arraySignal<T>(initialValue: T[]): ArraySignal<T> {
  const internal = signal(initialValue) as SignalGetter<T[]> & WritableSignal<T[]>;
  const node = internal[SIGNAL];
  return Object.assign(internal, {
    push: (item: T) => signalMutateFn(node, (x) => {
      x.push(item);
      return x;
    }),
    updateElement: (item: T, updateFn: (x: T) => T) => {
      signalMutateFn(node, (x) => {
        const index = x.indexOf(item);
        (index !== -1) && (x[index] = updateFn(item));
      })
    }
  })
}
```